# Web scraping in add ons(made from java script)

Tags: jquery, python, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to extract contact details from a web-site contact/about us section using add ons, I am not able to run python nor would prefer to install packages to run node.js ,how can I extract data.

Comment: Hi, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight _exactly_ what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sir I need to build an addon that extracts contact information from the currently opened web page in a browser and  as add ons are written in java script .so answer for the same.